# How to clean border noise from a license plate using filters

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing

I am filtering an image so that it removes noise from them.

This image corresponds to a patent plate, and to detect the letters I need them to be without noise.

Original image:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Any way to make that 5 able to remove white part from above? or decrease it

I have a couple of images like this with that problem, which occurs when I transform the image horizontally. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Is this your input image? or is it already processed (threshold etc.)? If it is not the original input image, it would be a good idea to post it along with the code of what you have already tried.

Comment: Great idea, updated

Comment: I still don't see your input image

Comment: Updated with input image

Comment: What do you call noise ? I don't see any.

Comment: I ask my self why you have such images in the first place. rather than finding a way to get images like that through your recognition you should a) capture larger images or crop the plate properly and b) pick OCR techniques that can deal with characters like that.

Comment: As I see it, the original image is not exactly the original image. This is a rotated image. This means that the angle of rotation is known. This means that the black triangles could be made white during the turn. Then there would be no problem deleting them.

Comment: When you rotate image set borderValue is white color in warpAffine() function.

Answer (score 1):

With just low-level operations (filters), you can't reduce the black area on the top because is it of the same nature as the characters themselves. Any action you take against this zone will also damage the characters. No filter will work satisfactorily.

Hence you must use some extra contextual information such as "against the top edge", and possibly "forming a straight edge". Even so, finding the exact border with the 5 is challenging.